# Image print quality check

Tags: php, image

Usual basic criteria for images in digital print are

- CMYK
- 300 dpi
- right scale

**Is there a possibility to compare user uploaded image to placed print standard?**

(Using PHP and perhaps some extension e.g. ImageMagic)

Idea is if user uploads bad print quality image e.g. jpg 100x100px @ 72dpi notice user in proper way. But after all research I have made, couldn't define some model how to extract uploaded image data and do compare/check.

Any idea how to aproach this problem would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [Imagick::getImageResolution](http://be.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageresolution.php) to get the resolution in dpi and you have [getimagesize](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), there you check for the channels, 4 is cmyk, 3 rgb.